# How to exit Ubuntu emergency mode

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ssd, login

When I logout and login again, my Ubuntu directly entered the emergency mode. Next are some background showed the operations I used before I entered the emergency mode. After that are the approaches I have already tried and then the conclusion of my problems.

**Background :**

I'm not sure if the following have any thing to do with my problem, but leave it as a reference.

Before I reboot ubuntu, I was trying to change the permission of my serial port. I use some commands like `chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0` and `sudo usermod -aG dialout my_user_name`, and then I logout but when I login again, after opening some browser, the system was frozen and I had to force my computer to reboot by using the power button, then it entered the emergency mode.

**My approaches :**

I tried to edited the `/etc/fstab` file and commented out one of my two ssd which I think was broken (but I'm not sure). After that I can reboot my system normally, but I can't log in to any of my users on Ubuntu, even I entered the correct password it just jumped back to the login menu and stuck at the login loop.

To solve the login loop problem, I pressed `ctrl + alt + F3` and tried to find the `Xauthority` file as many others suggested, but I couldn't find the file and it didn't showed in the `/run/user/1000/gdm3`, actually there was no `gdm3` directory on my system. I also found that my home directory were empty, so I added one myself and after that I can login successfully but all my files were gone.

**Concluding my problems :**

1. enter the emergency mode when use both of my ssd
2. losing all my files and stuck in the login loop when comment out one of the ssd in `/etc/fstab`

I am thinking that maybe all my files (including those in the home directory) are stored in the broken ssd which I commented out in the `/etc/fstab`, so my system can't read those files.

Please let me know is there anything to do to fix my system.

**edited :**

`journalctl -xb` showed :

```
systemd-fsck[727] : fsck failed with exit status 4
systemd[1] : systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-{my_disk}.service : failed with result 'exit code'
systemd[1] : Failed to start File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/{mu_disk}.
```

and my `/etc/fstab` showed that {my_disk}'s mount point was `/home`, so I commented out {my_disk} and reboot again, it can successfully booting and was able to login. After that I tried the top rated answer from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646414/welcome-to-emergency-mode-think-it-is-a-fsck-problem) to fix my disk but `fsck -y /dev/sdb1` didn't work.
The message after I entered `fsck -y /dev/sdb1` was :

```
ext2fs_check_desc: Corrupt group descriptor: bad block for block bitmap
fsck.ext4: Invalid argument while using the backup blocksfsck.ext4: going back to original superblock
Error reading block 121667583 (Invalid argument). Ignore error? yes

Force rewrite? yes

Superblock has an invalid journal (inode 8).
Clear? yes

*** journal has been deleted ***

The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 244190208 blocks
The physical size of the device is 12244 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort? yes

Error writing block 121667583 (Invalid argument). Ignore error? yes

/dev/sdb1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
```

Comment: chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0 and sudo usermod -aG dialout my_user_name  is not relevant to your boot issue.   It seems like you need to recover or recreate the data from the SSD in paths visible on the filesystem, but really, you don't provide sufficient information for us to advise further.

Comment: There is some problem that is preventing going to graphics mode, but we have no details and you have apparently did more than just these two commands. Try to type `exit` or Ctrl-D to exit emergency mode, or type “reboot” to try again.

Comment: @harrymc @davidgo I have updated more information regarding `journalctl -xb` and `fsck -y /dev/sdb1`. My computer is still broken and please let me know if there is any other information that I can provide to fix this problem, thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems like you have a corrupted disk. If you have backups for its data, just re-format it. But not if it contains irreplaceable important data.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the suggestion, but I would rather not format the disk since it contains somebody else's data. Is there any way that I can fix this disk without formatting it?

Comment: The question isn't to fix, but rather to salvage. Post the SMART data of the disk, to see if the disk is worth salvaging.